# Perform Load Testing in Insomnia

Tags: rest, insomnia

Can I have some guidance on how to perform load testing by sending multiple POST API calls within a stipulated time frame n Insomnia.
To achieve this, I have to POST the API calls in a for loop going from 0 to 500 in a span of 5 sec.
What can I do to implement this ?

Answer (score 9):

Hold CTRL and click the Send button - then select Repeat on Interval and type in the interval you need (I tested with 0.2 sec intervals so you can go pretty low if needed)